# Javascript multiple boxes design

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-framework, jquery-events

I am writing a script using jQuery to add multiple control boxes(divs) to a web page. These divs contain controls (anchors) like close, prev, next, search etc. A code sample:

```
$div_overlay = 
    $('<div></div>')
    .addClass('overlay')
    .append($('<div></div>')
        .addClass('text_controls')
//The onClick method below works perfect but not .click() of jQuery(due to the way 'index' is used)
        .append($('<a onClick="overlay_hide('+index+'); return false;"></a>')
            .addClass('close')
            .attr('href','#')
            /*.click(function(){
//The 'index' gets incremented as divs are created and hence a wrong value(the last one) is passed irrespective of the div clicked 
            overlay_hide(index)
            })*/
        )
```

'index' is a global var to keep track of the 'overlay' divs created.
It is incremented as the divs are created and each div is pushed in an array as it is created. So, 'index' is basically the array index of a div.

To keep it simple, I only added the 'close' anchor. The `$div_overlay` is in a function which is called every time an image is clicked.

My problem is to handle the click events for the anchors like 'close'. I would like to identify the div for which the anchor is clicked using an 'index' which is a global var.

I would like to be able to pass a reference to the div on which the close action is performed. If I use the jQuery click method which is commented in above code to close the div, it passes the last index value as the parameter to `overlay_hide()` (since index is incremented as the divs are created). If I use the onClick method as above, it works fine by passing the correct index value.

So, how do I identify these divs using indexes and be able to uniquely access them based on which div control is clicked? (Probably objects need to be used but I am not sure.)

One way would be to get the parent of the clicked anchor but I do not want to do it that way and would like to use an index.

Comment: You should not be giving the same "id" value to multiple elements. If you gave them unique "id" values, then all you'd have to do is check to see which `<div>` the clicked control is in.

Comment: I edited my post to remove the id. That was my mistake. I do not want to identify them by id or class names. I would like to know how to identify these dynamically created divs which I am storing in an array by their index values when an anchor is clicked with in one of these divs. My problem is that when the event is fired, I want the handler to pass the correct identifier for the div in which the anchor is clicked so that I can close that div.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to add an "id" or a "class" value? That's how I would do it because it would make everything so easy.

Comment: Well, I agree that it would be easy to use id or classes and I am not against it but I would like to know the "other ways" I could do this, one being using an index for the array in which they are stored. I actually wanted to learn how to handle this kind of coding problem where a global var will be used inside an event handler and the handler should use that value of the global var when the handler function is defined but not the modified value when the global var is updated after the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add meta data to the anchor with a data attribute.

```
$('<a data-index="' + index + '"></a>').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    overlay_hide(data.index); // note index will be a string
    return false;
});
```

Another way you could do it is with a closure on the click function:

```
$('<a />').click(function(i){
    return function(e){
        // use i here this is the callback.
        overlay_hide(i);
        return false;
    };
}(index));
```

I would also like to point out that you have an id `.attr('id','overlay')` being added - and id's must be unique across the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy - No, it will turn the data properties into a javascript object whose key is data-**key**.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean; right.  If it were me, I'd put the data on the container `<div>` and not the individual `<a>` elements, because then a single handler could just determine what to do by the DOM structure itself.  In fact, it doesn't really need an "id" at all; the overlay container could just get the class "overlay", and then the handler would look for ".closest('div.overlay')" as the operation target.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about closures and scope in JS: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures

Quick fix to your problem:

```
var closeButton = (function(index){
    return $('<a></a>').addClass('close').attr('href','#').click(function(){
        overlay_hide(index);
    })
})(index);
var $div_overlay = $('<div></div>').attr('id','overlay').append(
    $('<div></div>').addClass('text_controls').append(closeButton)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be so much easier to just use the "overlay" class that's on the container:

```
$('body').delegate('a.close', 'click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div.overlay').hide();
});
```

Just set that up, and things like it for the other types of control, and then you don't have to worry about sticking those ugly DOM0 handlers in your added tags at all.

I know you said you "don't want to do it that way", but unless you can explain why such an exercise is valuable in general, it seems unethical not to recommend the most obvious way to go about solving the problem.

Comment: thanks for your ideas on using .closest(). I knew we could do it using classes but I was thinking on terms of using .parent() or something like that and did not give it much thought. However, because I started using the index approach to grab the correct div and got stuck with using global vars inside handlers, I wanted to know the coding principles to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the live() function, read this:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: What kind of answer is this? explain what you mean or this is a terrible answer.

Comment: calm down, the live() applies to the appended div and its click(), this would help to add the click and avoid the onClick, at least I think it would. P.S. the OP says: "My problem is to handle the click events", the live will add the click event.

Comment: Actually I think using a single handler with ".delegate()" or ".live()" would in fact be the best, easiest way to do this. However it would have been nice for @jackJoe to provide at least a skeletal example.

Comment: I would agree that live or delegate would be better especially if there are a lot of these dynamic overlays. But to answer this question you must say something about how to handle the index.

Comment: I agree with @Josiah Ruddell. I would like to know how to identify these dynamically created divs which I am storing in an array by their index values when an anchor is clicked with in one of these divs. However, I do not understand why I should be using .live() here. I don't have a problem attaching an event handler to my anchors. My problem is that when the event is fired, I want the handler to pass the correct identifier for the div in which the anchor is clicked so that I can close that div.

Comment: @Pointy and @jackJoe How is that .live() will handle my problem? I do not have an issue attaching event handlers for anchors as each anchor created has it's .click() method. I want to know how I can pass the correct index in the overlay_hide() method

Comment: I thought you had a problem binding the click() event, and that's what live() would solve and that's why I suggested it, but to solve the index problem, I think using classes (check Pointy's third comment on Josiah Ruddell's post) is the best way, I too have problems with indexes and usually resort to using the classname.

Comment: @jackJoe Got you. Classes would be safe. I just explained in my comment to the question as to what I am actually trying to do. I think Josiah Ruddell's solution addresses what I am trying to do.